# Can Rogue Rannie get knocked out?

Tags: dragons-crown

Can rogue rannie, your partner (the thief) in dragon's crown, be knocked out or killed?
if he could be, what happens? I won't be able to open chests or doors anymore?

Comment: I've seen him taking damage and getting burned, but didn't tested let him die. Will try that sometime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, of course not, just like the fairy. From technical point his functions are mostly aesthetical, but he is also collecting coins/treasures for you.